# How can I autoload singleton's in DooPHP?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, singleton, doophp

I'm new to DooPHP, but it's freaking awesome so far. I'm just not sure how to autoload my own classes as singletons. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [You dont need Singletons in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4595964/who-needs-singletons/4596323#4596323)

Comment: But it's a shared class with shared data that's global per instance accessible from a variety of methods

Comment: Use a regular class, dont instantiate it twice and pass it to the code that needs it. See http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RlfLCWKxHJ0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give your class a singleton method if you want to.

```
class Test {
    protected static $_instance;

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$_instance===null){
             self::$_instance = new Test();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }
}
```

Use this wherever you want Test::getInstance();

Alternatively, you can create an instance of your class and set it to DooConfig object.

```
Doo::conf()->test = new Test();
//Or this in common.conf.php
$config['test'] = new Test();
```

Answer (score 0):

Save it in the /protected/class folder. And it will be loaded automatically.
Otherwise, check DooLoader.

Comment: why not? There is no connection between loading class and structure of the class?

Comment: Well.. I need it to be instantiated globally so I can use it across various methods